# Google.Apis.GoogleAnalyticsAdmin.v1alpha raising insufficientPermissions when trying to get google admin analytics account detail in C#?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I wanted to get the account detail, after authenticating I added to the scope section to grant the permission, but when running the code it raised an error insufficient permission, I don't know what step I missed, how would I be able to fix this error?

```
private static GoogleAnalyticsAdminService _analyticsService;
        

  public static void IntializeAnalytics() {
      GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
            
      if (CloudManager.Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
      {
         credential = CloudManager.Credential.CreateScoped( 
         GoogleAnalyticsAdminService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly, GoogleAnalyticsAdminService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,
                GoogleAnalyticsAdminService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsersReadonly, GoogleAnalyticsAdminService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit);
            }
      _analyticsService = new GoogleAnalyticsAdminService(
       new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
                  
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = CloudManager.ApplicationName

       });

      var response =  _analyticsService.Accounts.Get("accounts/Default Account for Firebase").Execute();
            
}
```

Error message :

```
   Unhandled exception. The service analyticsadmin has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is Forbidden.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service analyticsadmin has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I edited it above, the full error message is included

Comment: Why are you using alpha you should be using beta.

Comment: I followed the google doc, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/quickstart-client-libraries

Comment: okay I will have a look at that in the morning think that sample needs updating I will contact the team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means that when you authorized your application you did not request the proper scopes.  Im not sure where you got that code from Its nothing like the code I normally use.

```
using Google.Analytics.Admin.V1Beta;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


// Path to the service account credentials file. 
const string credentialsJsonPath = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\ServiceAccountCred.json";

// Property on Google analytics which the service account has been granted access to.
const string propertyId = "XXXXXX";

var client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClientBuilder()
{
    CredentialsPath = credentialsJsonPath
}.Build();

var response = client.ListAccounts(new ListAccountsRequest());

foreach (var account in response) {
    Console.WriteLine(account.Name);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use application default credential instead of OAuth 2/ service account credential ?

Comment: that depends on what you mean by application default credentials?   you just want to use the env var?

Comment: The credential that is generated using the gcloud cli -- to use my own user credentials for my application to access an API -- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default

Comment: gcloud cli is not the same as google developer console TBH I have never tried.   I would follow the documentation

Comment: the issue is still with how you are apparently scopes and the fact that you are using alpha not with the service account itself

Comment: Hey DalmTo, I used your code the above one and I get nothing in my console, I have Default Account for Firebase on my analytics account but it is returning empty , why is that?

Comment: Service account doesnt have access to any google analytics accounts.  Try taking the service account email address and going to the google analytics website under the admin section and adding it as a user

Comment: Adding the service account email address to the google analytics resolved the issue. Thanks DalmTo!

Comment: Service accounts need to be preauthorized.  Once you have granted it access it should have access until someone has removed it.